# How to put an additional image or rectangle on the bottom of Sprite?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I need to add an icon on the bottom of the Sprite `worker` and then change this icon randomly at each iteration. Please notice that the Sprite `worker` has 2 states: `RUNNING` and `IDLE`. In each of these states, the `worker` has a specific image. What I need now is to put an **additional** small image on the **bottom of worker** that will specify **emotional state**: `HAPPY` or `ANGRY`.

In the class `Worker` I create the array `emo_images` and also specify the variable `emo_state`. This variable denotes an emotional state of the `worker`: happy or angry. Each emotional state has its image stored in `emotional_images`.

In the code I randomly generate the variable `state_indicator`. If it's greater than 9, then the emotional state of the `worker` is changed to `ANGRY`. Otherwise, it's happy.

```
   state_indicator = random.randint(0,10)
    if state_indicator > 9:
        print(state_indicator)
        self.alert_notif_worker()

    def alert_notif_worker(self):
        self.emo_state = Worker.ANGRY
```

However I don't not know how to put the emotional image on the bottom of the `worker` image, because I don't want to replace the `worker` image (IDLE, RUNNING). I only need to add another image on the bottom and this additional image should move together with the `worker`.

If it's very difficult to do, then it would be also fine to have rectangles of two colours: red and green, instead of images, in order to indicate emotional states.

Complete code:

```
import sys
import pygame, random
from pygame.math import Vector2
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import math


WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (20, 255, 140)
GREY = (210, 210 ,210)
BLACK = (0, 0 ,0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
PURPLE = (255, 0, 255)


SCREENWIDTH=1000
SCREENHEIGHT=578
# Create point vectors for the corners.
corners = [
    Vector2(0, 0), Vector2(SCREENWIDTH, 0),
    Vector2(SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT), Vector2(0, SCREENHEIGHT)
    ]

ABS_PATH = "/Users/sb/Desktop/"
IMG_BACKGROUND = ABS_PATH + "images/background.jpg"
IMG_WORKER_RUNNING = ABS_PATH + "images/workers/worker_1.png"
IMG_WORKER_IDLE = ABS_PATH + "images/workers/worker_2.png"
IMG_WORKER_ACCIDENT = ABS_PATH + "images/workers/accident.png"
IMG_WORKER_HAPPY = ABS_PATH + "images/workers/happy.png"
IMG_WORKER_ANGRY = ABS_PATH + "images/workers/angry.png"


class Background(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image_file, location, *groups):
        # we set a _layer attribute before adding this sprite to the sprite groups
        # we want the background to be actually in the back
        self._layer = -1
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, groups)
        # let's resize the background image now and only once
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(image_file).convert(), (SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=location)


class Worker(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    RUNNING = 0
    IDLE = 1
    HAPPY = 0
    ANGRY = 1
    IMAGE_CACHE = {}

    def __init__(self, idw, image_running, image_idle, image_happy, image_angry, location, *groups):

        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 20)

        # each state has it's own image
        self.images = {
            Worker.RUNNING: pygame.transform.scale(self.get_image(image_running), (45, 45)),
            Worker.IDLE: pygame.transform.scale(self.get_image(image_idle), (20, 45))
        }

        self.emo_images = {
            Worker.HAPPY: pygame.transform.scale(self.get_image(image_happy), (20, 20)),
            Worker.ANGRY: pygame.transform.scale(self.get_image(image_angry), (20, 20))
        }


        # we set a _layer attribute before adding this sprite to the sprite groups
        # we want the workers on top
        self._layer = 0
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, groups)

        self.idw = idw

        # let's keep track of the state and how long we are in this state already            
        self.state = Worker.IDLE
        self.emo_state = Worker.HAPPY
        self.ticks_in_state = 0

        self.image = self.images[self.state]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=location)

        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
        self.speed = random.randint(1, 3)
        self.set_random_direction()


    def set_random_direction(self):
        # random new direction or standing still
        vec = pygame.math.Vector2(random.randint(-100,100), random.randint(-100,100)) if random.randint(0, 5) > 1 else pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)

        # check the new vector and decide if we are running or not
        length = vec.length()
        speed = sum(abs(int(v)) for v in vec.normalize() * self.speed) if length > 0 else 0

        if (length == 0 or speed == 0) and (self.state != Worker.ACCIDENT):
            new_state = Worker.IDLE
            self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2(0, 0)
        else:
            new_state = Worker.RUNNING
            self.direction = vec.normalize()

        self.ticks_in_state = 0
        self.state = new_state

        # use the right image for the current state
        self.image = self.images[self.state]
        #self.emo_image = self.emo_images[self.emo_state]


    def update(self, screen):
        self.ticks_in_state += 1

        # the longer we are in a certain state, the more likely is we change direction
        if random.randint(0, self.ticks_in_state) > 70:
            self.set_random_direction()

        # now let's multiply our direction with our speed and move the rect
        vec = [int(v) for v in self.direction * self.speed]
        self.rect.move_ip(*vec)

        # if we're going outside the screen, change direction
        if not screen.get_rect().contains(self.rect):
            self.direction = self.direction * -1


        send_alert = random.randint(0,10)
        if send_alert > 9:
            print(send_alert)
            self.alert_notif_worker()

        self.rect.clamp_ip(screen.get_rect())


    def alert_notif_worker(self):
        self.emo_state = Worker.ANGRY


    def get_image(self,key):
        if not key in Worker.IMAGE_CACHE:
            Worker.IMAGE_CACHE[key] = pygame.image.load(key)
        return Worker.IMAGE_CACHE[key]




pygame.init()

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
workers = pygame.sprite.Group()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("TEST")

# create multiple workers
idw = 1
for pos in ((30,30), (50, 400), (200, 100), (700, 200)):
    Worker(idw, IMG_WORKER_RUNNING, IMG_WORKER_IDLE, 
           IMG_WORKER_HAPPY, IMG_WORKER_ANGRY, 
           pos, all_sprites, workers)
    idw+=1

# and the background
Background(IMG_BACKGROUND, [0,0], all_sprites)

carryOn = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while carryOn:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            carryOn = False
            pygame.display.quit()
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    all_sprites.update(screen)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(20)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd either use Micheal O'Dwyer's solution and blit the icon images in a separate for loop or create an `Icon` sprite class which can be added as an attribute to the `Worker` class. Then you can just update the position of the icon sprite in the `update` method and swap the image when the workers state gets changed.

You need a `LayeredUpdates` group, so that the icon appears above the worker sprite.

```
import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2


pg.init()
WORKER_IMG = pg.Surface((30, 50))
WORKER_IMG.fill(pg.Color('dodgerblue1'))
ICON_HAPPY = pg.Surface((12, 12))
ICON_HAPPY.fill(pg.Color('yellow'))
ICON_ANGRY = pg.Surface((10, 10))
ICON_ANGRY.fill(pg.Color('red'))


class Worker(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, all_sprites):
        super().__init__()
        self._layer = 0
        self.image = WORKER_IMG
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.state = 'happy'
        self.emo_images = {'happy': ICON_HAPPY, 'angry': ICON_ANGRY}
        # Create an Icon instance pass the image, the position
        # and add it to the all_sprites group.
        self.icon = Icon(self.emo_images[self.state], self.rect.bottomright)
        self.icon.add(all_sprites)

    def update(self):
        # Update the position of the icon sprite.
        self.icon.rect.topleft = self.rect.bottomright

    def change_state(self):
        """Change the state from happy to angry and update the icon."""
        self.state = 'happy' if self.state == 'angry' else 'angry'
        # Swap the icon image.
        self.icon.image = self.emo_images[self.state]


class Icon(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, image, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self._layer = 1
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=pos)


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.LayeredUpdates()
    worker = Worker((50, 80), all_sprites)
    all_sprites.add(worker)

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEMOTION:
                worker.rect.center = event.pos
            elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                worker.change_state()

        all_sprites.update()
        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be accomplished fairly easily, by just blitting each `Worker`'s emotion image, at a certain location, in relation to the `Worker`'s `rect.x`, and `rect.y` co-ordinates.

Unfortunately, I cannot test the code example below, because your code uses lots of images which I don't have. One problem I do see which you will need to fix before trying to implement this code, is that the `Background` object you are initializing is being added to `all_sprites`, so you may consider changing `all_sprites` to `all_workers`, and maybe add `Background` to a different group.

You will also need to initialize `offset_x`, and `offset_y` to values which work for you. The values used below will just move the image to the bottom left corner of the worker.

Here is the example code:

```
for worker in all_workers:
   offset_x = 0
   offset_y = worker.rect.height
   screen.blit(worker.emo_images[worker.emo_state], (worker.rect.x+offset_x, worker.rect.y+offset_y))
```

I hope this answer helps you! Please let me know if this works for you, and if you have any further questions, feel free to leave a comment below.